# How to slide or hide a div with transition in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I am trying to display a div with the click of a button with slide effect. When something is clicked, it will toggle as shown or invisible with slide effect. I have achieved this so far by doing this.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
    myclass: '',
    }
 this.divclicked = this.divclicked.bind(this);
 }

 divclicked() {
  if (this.state.myclass === '') {
   this.setState({
    myclass: 'coolclass'
   })
  }
 else {
  this.setState({
    myclass: '',
  })
 }
}

render() {
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <div id="box" onClick={this.divclicked}>
    </div>
    <div id="seconddiv" className={this.state.myclass}>
     <p>help help</p>
     <p>help help</p>
     <p>help help</p>
     <p>help help</p>
     <p>help help</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

And my CSS

```
#box {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: red
}

#seconddiv.coolclass{
 height:300px;
 background: purple;
}

#seconddiv {
 height: 0px;
 transition: 0.5s;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

So here, when the red box with the id of "box" is clicked, I give the "seconddiv" a className and CSS takes care of hiding the div. The problem is that when I am giving the className `coolclass`, I do not want to use px but want to use percentage. So currently, it is going from 0px to 300px. But I want it to go from 0px to 100%; How do I achieve this. When I try to put the height of 100% in seconddiv, the slide animation doesn't work.

Comment: Hope [`animate.css`](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) package might help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set your initial height to `0%`. You also need to give `.App` a height of `100%` so that it stretches the full height of the window. In this example, I gave it a static height of 1200px, but that should be determined by the body.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
   super();
   this.state = {
    myclass: '',
    }
 this.divclicked = this.divclicked.bind(this);
 }

 divclicked() {
  if (this.state.myclass === '') {
   this.setState({
    myclass: 'coolclass'
   })
  }
 else {
  this.setState({
    myclass: '',
  })
 }
}

render() {
 return (
  <div className="App">
    <div id="box" onClick={this.divclicked}>
    </div>
    <div id="seconddiv" className={this.state.myclass}>
     <p>help help</p>
     <p>help help</p>
     <p>help help</p>
     <p>help help</p>
     <p>help help</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  );
 }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
#box {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 background-color: red
}

#seconddiv.coolclass{
 max-height:100%;
 background: purple;
}

#seconddiv {
 max-height: 0%;
 transition: 0.5s;
 overflow: hidden;
}
.App {
  height: 100%;
}
#root {
  height: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But what I was trying to do was make the seconddiv grow only upto the five p tags, or have its height onclick equal to whatever the children require. Currently, on the code you provided, the height covers the full view of the page. Sorry I didnt make that clear earlier.

Comment: @craftdeer Okay, updated answer to correct that. You need to give `.App` a height of `100%` and your `#root` div that renders your entire React App needs a set height. You also need to change the transition from using `height` to using `max-height`.

Comment: Great. Thank you. 
Why did you have to set the App height to 100% for it to work and root's height 1200px?

Comment: @craftdeer It's because when you use percentages, it's based off of that elements **parent**. So by default, elements get `height: auto`. `100%` of `auto` doesn't work, so that means `.App` needs to have a set height so that the child divs can use that in their height percentage calculation. But, when we look at the parent for `.App`, it also doesn't have a heigh set, so `100%` on `.App` wouldn't work either. So, starting from the top, if `#root` is `1200px` tall, then `.App` is `100%` of `1200px`. Now, our children have a set height that they can use to toggle from 0 - 100%. Hope that helps.

Comment: Wonderful. One last question promise. When you set root height to 1200px, isnt that going to cause problems if I add more contents to my page and the heights of these contents exceed 1200px?

Comment: Right, this was just for the example. In your real app, you should add `height: 100%` to `body` and `#root`: `body, #root { height: 100% }`

Answer (score 2):

You can just combine **conditional rendering** ( **x && y** ) with some **scale animation**

Example

```
const scaleAnimationIn = keyframes`
  0% {
    transform: scale(0, 1);
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
`


const QuestionHeaderPausedText = styled.div`
   animation: ${scaleAnimationIn} 1s;
   animation-delay: 7s;
   animation-fill-mode: both;
`
```

In the return/render method just:

```
{isSomeConditionTrue && <QuestionHeaderPausedText>
   My text
</QuestionHeaderPausedText>}
```

This example use Styled Components but the method (scaling) will work with any css solution.